# Vue.Js - Firebase functions cannot be used on components

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, firebase-storage

I was using Vue Resource in posting data from my web app to the firebase. but then, I just found out that I need to use firebase integration to upload IMAGES in the firebase storage. so I integrated it in my src/main.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import App from './App.vue'
import Routes from './routes'

Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: Routes,
  mode: 'history'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  router: router,
  created () {
    firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: 'AIzaSyDhdEhcLPfGqo5_msnhVKWH9BkZNOc6RYw',
      authDomain: 'nots-76611.firebaseapp.com',
      databaseURL: 'https://nots-76611.firebaseio.com',
      projectId: 'nots-76611',
      storageBucket: 'gs://nots-76611.appspot.com'
    })
  }
})
```

but when I tried to use it in one of my components' methods:

```js
methods: {
    post: function(){
      //for(var i = 0; i < this.tailors.length; i++){
      //  if(this.$route.params.id == this.tailors[i].id)
      //    this.ready_to_wear.tailor_name = this.tailors[i].tName;
      //}
      //this.$http.post('https://nots-76611.firebaseio.com/ready_to_wear.json', this.ready_to_wear);
      let key
      firebase.database().ref('ready_to_wears').push(this.ready_to_wear)
        .then((data) => {
          key = data.key
          return key
        })
        .then(key => {
          const filename = this.image.name
          const ext = filename.slice(filename.lastIndexOf('.'))
          return firebase.storage().ref('rtws/' + key + '.' + ext).put(this.image)
        })
        .then(fileData => {
          imageUrl = fileData.metadata.downloadURLs[0]
          return firebase.database().ref('ready_to_wears').child(key).update({rtwImg: imageUrl})
        });
    }
}
```

.. it says in the console log that `'firebase' is not defined`

I'm guessing that firebase functions can't be used in the components even though it is integrated in the main.js

How do I make use of it in the components? is there any other way around it?

Comment: Just import it in any file you need to use it. `import firebase from 'firebase'`. You didn't integrate it with vue, you just used the reference. `vue-fire` will integrate it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't appear to be using VueFire, which I believe exposes firebase through a Vue prototype property as $firebase. However, you can do it yourself manually.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import App from './App.vue'
import Routes from './routes'

Vue.prototype.$firebase = firebase
```

After that, firebase will be available in *every* Vue or component as `this.$firebase`.

```
methods: {
    post: function(){
        this.$firebase.database().ref() ... etc ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Bert - where would the typical `firebase.initializeApp({})` code go? Would it be before the `Vue.prototype.$firebase = firebase`?

Comment: @JoeManFoo In most cases, yes, you would initialize firebase outside of Vue or in the created handler of the root Vue. Here is an example from VueFire: https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire#usage